# How is the curved top of the WWII Aid station tent made?

Tags: part-identification, design

How did they make the curved top of the tent in the [WWII Aid station](https://www.bricklink.com/v3/studio/design.page?idModel=245880)?

[image: constructed WWII Aid station LEGO set]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I assume you aren't looking for complete instructions, but rather interested in main element used to construct tent. In such case [Sports Arena Section / Skateboard Ramp (43085)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=43085#T=C) has been used in Tan.

[image]

Answer (score 18):

The models featured on Bricklink include a parts list, model file and instructions. You can see there that the curved tent is a [skateboard ramp](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=43085&name=Sports%20Arena%20Section%20/%20Skateboard%20Ramp&category=%5BSports%5D) and the edges are 1x4 tiles attached with Technic pin 1/2.

Comment: This is a much better answer - it actually shows how to get the desired information given what the asker knows.